# No resource identifier found for attribute 'counterEnabled'

Tags: android, textinputlayout

> 

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/input_email"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="10"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/email_hint"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/password_hint"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/save"
    android:layout_gravity="end"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/success"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/success"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Whats the problem? I got compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0' in my gradle file, also compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0' .Why is this not working? and why do i get this strange error?

Comment: soled it via, updating compiledsdkversion to latest.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem in 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0',
because when i use 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1' ,I have the same problem.*No resource identifier found for attribute 'counterEnabled'*,
than change 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1' to 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1' ,this problem has been solved.

[the location of attribute '23.1.1'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Srr4v.png)

[the location of attribute '23.0.1'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myNge.png)